# How to derive $\;a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)\;?$

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

I'm studying in 8th grade in India. I saw the question in my FIITJEE textbook, but it was not shown how to derive it. Please help. My mid phase examinations are coming up.

Comment: All the answers are really nice. But to see how that factors like that, I would use factor theorem and you can see that a solution of the above (=0) equation is $a=-b$ so you know instantly that $(a+b)$ and then you can do algebraic division to the rest? (This is the assumption that the level of the expression implies you know the techniques I suggested) :)

Answer (score 8):

Note that $-1$ is a root of polynomial $f = x^{3} + 1$.

Thus $x+ 1$ divides $f$.

Do long division to find
$$
x^{3} + 1 = (x+1)(x^{2} - x + 1).
$$
Now substitute $x = a/b$ and multiply both sides by $b^{3}$ to get the equality.

Of course the equality is trivial if $b = 0$.

Answer (score 7):

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)=(a+b)\{(a+b)^2-3ab\}=\cdots$$

Comment: I believe that this is the best way to derive it on the spot... well I begin with $(a+b)^3=\cdots$ and go from there.

Answer (score 3):

$(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=a^3-a^2b+ab^2+a^2b-ab^2+b^3=a^3+b^3$

Answer (score 3):

In general (and straighforward):

$$a^{n}-b^{n}=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\cdots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1}\right)$$

If $n$ is odd then $\left(-b\right)^{n}=-b^{n}$ and application gives: $$a^{n}+b^{n}=a^{n}-\left(-b\right)^{n}=(a+b)(\cdots)$$

Answer (score 2):

Start with $$\color{grey}{\boxed{\displaystyle\color{white}{\overline{\underline{\color{black}{\,a^n-c^n=\left(a-c\right)\left( a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}c+\cdots+ac^{n-2}+c^{n-1}\right)\quad n\in\mathbb N.\,}}}}}}$$
 and set $n=3$ and $c=-b.$

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+b)^3=(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)$$

You just multiply it and get:

$$(a+b)^3=(a+b)(a+b)(a+b)=(a^2+2ab+b^2)(a+b)=$$

$$=a^3+2a^2 b+ab^2+a^2 b+2ab^2+b^3=a^3+3a^2 b+3ab^2+b^3$$

So:

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-(3a^2 b+3ab^2)=(a+b)^3-3[ab(a+b)]$$

You factor  out $(a+b)$:

$$(a+b)^3-3(ab(a+b))= (a+b)^3-(a+b)3ab=(a+b)[(a+b)^2-3ab]$$

When you expand (a+b) squared you get

$$(a+b)[(a+b)^2-3ab]=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2).$$

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were confused or misled by the word "derive" here. Sometimes, when asked to *derive* or *prove* an equation, all that is being asked for is that you *check* that the two sides of the equation are indeed equal by 'multiplying out' any complex  terms (the right hand side in this case) and ending up with the same term on each side. So @JasperLoy's simple answer would (by my lights) do just fine.